# Where can I find the /dev/st tape drivers on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, devices, storage

Working on setting up Amazon VTL on Ubuntu, and I'm missing one step.

```
iscsiadm --mode node --targetname iqn.1997-05.com.amazon:...
```

...command creates `/dev/sg0` and not `/dev/st*` as I would like.

I've read that installing the [SCSI Tape high-level driver](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man4/st.4.html), e.g. `modprobe st` on other Linux OSes, works.  But there doesn't seem to be a `st` driver on Ubuntu Xenial.

How do I get the high-level `st` SCSI tape driver on Ubuntu?

**Edit**

It looks like this driver is available on stock 18.04, and the Azure's 16.04

`/lib/modules/4.15.0-20-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/st.ko`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the root of the issue is that AWS Ubuntu images don't seem to have a 
`linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)` package.

I've found other linux-image-extra packages but none have a st.ko with the correct module format.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-aws/+bug/1678213

Answer (score 0):

Update 2021:

In the latest Ubuntu distributions, the `st` driver has been moved to package `linux-modules-extra-*` instead of `linux-image-extra-*`
which was mentioned three years ago.

On GCP Compute Engine for example, if you deploy a 20.04 instance, you need to additionally install package `linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-1035-gcp` for getting the `st` driver.

===========

Newer ubuntu images provisioned by cloud providers such as AWS and Azure seem lack of the `st` driver in the default setup as you metioned.

However,  you can get it back by installing a kernel of which the version with "sutible" `linux-image-extra` package.

For example, for ubuntu 16.04 family, you can install the kernel package `linux-image-extra-4.4.0-134-generic`. After reboot, you will have the `st.ko`.

ps1. you can check `st.ko` exist by `updatedb && locate st.ko|grep /st.ko`

ps2. if grub does not boot with the kernel version you wish, try the procedure mentioned here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2305787